# game design improvement

Tags: game-design, c#

I was having a discussion with my developer mate on following game design.

I have a collection of `Move` in the `Game` class. my developer mate is asking me to remove the collection and only have the current move information there.

what is your suggestions?

```
public class Game
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String CreatorId { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public List<Move> Moves { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Move
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String PlayerId { get; set; }
    public String PlayerName { get; set; }
    public String NextMoveId { get; set; }
    public String NextPlayerId { get; set; }
    public String Position { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: -1. While questions of this sort are generally appropriate here, there's just not enough information in this one. What kind of game are you making? How often do you look up moves? How many moves are there?

Comment: I think I have asked this question on a wrong place, SO is the best to ask every kind of questions. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407307/game-design-improvement

Comment: If it works, why mess with it. This is probably a better question to ask on SO. Still, having a list of moves could be useful, as long as it doesn't become a bottle neck. (do moves occur multiple times per frame, are large numbers of moves needed) I doubt there will be a problem though.

Answer (score 2):

I would say this question isn't related to game design but to software design or software architecture. Anyway, back to topic:

You question is really short and I can't tell what the classes are for but I will do a educated guess. I think `Game` is your global game context, which contains information several other objects are sharing.

The main question you should answer is: Does any other object need a list of `Move` or just the current one.

Sorry for the general answer but I can do bettw with more information.